# How To Remove, "Do You Want To Open This File"

Tags: windows, security-warning

Since 9/14/16 when new Windows updates were installed, each time I wish to open any in my 'Favorites' file, the , "Do you wish to open this file" message box appears - even for Gmail ! I'm thinking it may be due to enhanced security, but it's terribly annoying ! Can you please help ? I'm using Windows 8.1.
Thank you.

Comment: perhaps you could include an image, or type out the whole message in the box.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, edited .. you're not getting "How to open" you're getting the "Open File" warning found this:

http://www.askvg.com/how-to-fix-do-you-want-to-open-this-file-security-warning-while-opening-start-menu-or-taskbar-shortcuts-in-windows-vista-and-7/

You'll probably want just this one for now

ICACLS "%userprofile%\Favorites\Links" /Setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)Medium

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. "I'm using Windows 8.1" said the OP ...

Answer (score 0):

"Favorites" by default is a magic folder in the "internet explorer security zone," and if you move a file out of that to (for example) the desktop, you will probably not get the prompt.

There are ways to configure this zone with lower security to avoid these prompts, but IMO, it is better to not mix untrusted and trusted links/documents in this folder.

I believe that TG2's suggestion re: ICACLS is one way to configure the security for that zone (and the path in the command is the actual file-system path to the magic folder).

Microsoft has a decent article about configuring which is much too broad to quote here.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815141

If you are using "favorites" as a "shortcut bin" on the taskbar, then you can make a non-magic one by making a folder on your HDD, and then adding that folder as a toolbar (right-click taskbar > toolbar > new toolbar).  You can then add/remove toolbar shortcuts via the toolbar or by browsing to the folder in windows explorer.

Comment: As for why did it suddenly start now: either you never had non-internet links in there or the update reset the zone security.